# Javascript/Jquery to grab ID with different numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this to change the attributes

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl14_ucCal_hlRss').attr({
 title: "Subscribe via RSS"
});
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl14_ucCal_hlRss img').attr({
 title: "Subscribe via RSS",
 alt: "Subscribe via RSS"
});
```

It works well however I need to add this to multiple different websites where the "ctl14" will change (For example on another site it will be "ctl60"). Is there a way I can modify this to make sure it picks any numbers after "ctl##" then continues on with _ucCal_hlRss and _ucCal_hlRss img?

Comment: you can create a function or a loop, depending on your needs.

Comment: It would be best to assign a class that doesn't vary based on the site.

Comment: I am with @Barmar - those look like auto-generated IDs. And from my (very limited) experience with .NET it looks like the default value ID added when you add an element in WebForms using the WYSIWYG-y editor. At any rate, it doesn't look like they need to be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('[id^=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl][id$=_ucCal_hlRss]')
```

Try this selector, which will get all elements with an ID starting with ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl and finishing with _ucCal_hlRss.

Comment: Awesome, this works exactly how I wanted it to! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//function way

function subscribe_title(n) {
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl' + n + '_ucCal_hlRss').attr({
      title: "Subscribe via RSS"
    }).children('img').attr({
      title: "Subscribe via RSS",
      alt: "Subscribe via RSS"
    });
  } // end function;

//loop method, change the 30 to whatever number you have;
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl' + i + '_ucCal_hlRss').attr({
    title: "Subscribe via RSS"
  }).children('img').attr({
    title: "Subscribe via RSS",
    alt: "Subscribe via RSS"
  });
} // end for loop;

//using a pre-fetched array of numbers;
var nums = [100, 50, 16, 2];
for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl' + nums[i] + '_ucCal_hlRss').attr({
    title: "Subscribe via RSS"
  }).children('img').attr({
    title: "Subscribe via RSS",
    alt: "Subscribe via RSS"
  });
}

//perhaps the easiest way

$('div[id^=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl').attr({
  title: "Subscribe via RSS"
}).children('img').attr({
  title: "Subscribe via RSS",
  alt: "Subscribe via RSS"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl10_ucCal_hlRss">
  100
  <img src="//placekitten.com/300x300/" />
</div>
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl12_ucCal_hlRss">
  100
  <img src="//placekitten.com/300x300/" />
</div>
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl12_ucCal_hlRss">
  100
  <img src="//placekitten.com/300x300/" />
</div>
```